# Составной первичный ключ Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

[image: часть БД кафедры]

Проблема с **academic_plan_subject**. В MS SQL я мог так сделать, насколько помню, чтобы первичные ключи из других таблицы могли образовать составной первичный в третьей.
Можно ли в Django так сделать? И стоит ли?)
Это нарисовано в dbdesign.online

Comment: Нельзя, Django не поддерживает составные первичные ключи (просто составные не-первичные поддерживает, но толку от этого мало)

Comment: @andreymal либы из pypi тоже не особо?
Какие то находил но не решался пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем Вас понимаю. MS SQL - СУБД, Django - Framework. ORM Django умеет работать с различными СУБД по умолчанию это LiteSQL, postgresSQL, MySQL но можно и с MS SQL.

```
pip install django-mssql-backend
```

Ни кто Вам не запрещает работать с СУБД в обход ORM, хоть это и не желательно. Единственное чего Вам не стоит трогать это поле ID во всех таблицах, иначе слетит админка.

В Django не зависимо от СУБД (по умолчанию) PrimoryKey всегда ID, как я и говорил это нужно для работы панели администратора.
К сожалению Вы не описали задачу которую решаете, но я предполагаю что вариант с ForegenKey должен помочь.

```
#models.py
class academic_plan_subject(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        constraints = [models.UniqueConstraint(fields=[id_plan,id_subject], name='some_unique_name'] 
    id_plan=models.ForeignKey(academic_plan,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    id_subject=models.ForeignKey(subject,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: Неправда, primary key в Django отлично меняется, читайте внимательнее документацию https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields

Comment: Я и не говорил что он не меняется. Я сказал что по умолчанию он всегда весит на ID, и что если изменить его через СУБД а не ORM, получим проблемы с админкой.